# I want to get the text from the textfields as soon as their focus is lost. for this i tried using the "this" operator but it doesn't work

Tags: java, swing

i have a lot of textfields in my frame so it would be impossible to have a focus listener for each 1 of them. so i want to use a single focus listener function and get the text whenever the focus is lost.

```
        tf1=new JTextField();
        tf1.setBounds(200,300,150,50);
        tf1.setText("");
        tf1.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                tfFocusLost(evt);
            }
        });
        add(tf1);

        tf2=new JTextField();
        tf2.setBounds(200,500,150,50);
        tf2.setText("");
        tf2.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                tfFocusLost(evt);
            }
        });
        add(tf2);

    private void tfFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        s=this.getText();   
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: Can you improve the format of your code, and explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: the line s=this.getText() is giving the error

Comment: The `FocusEvent` provides the `source` and `component` properties from the field that triggered the event

Comment: Thanks for formatting. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the implementation for your tfFocusLost.

```
   private void tfFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        s=this.getText();   
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

instead of above you can use something like this.

```
 private void tfFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt, JTextField textField ) {
        s=textField.getText();   
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

And call it like  `tfFocusLost(evt,tf1);`

Comment: what changes should be made in this part of the code ?

Comment: tf2.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            tfFocusLost(evt);
        }
    });

Comment: @ChiragDhawan Instead of calling tfFocusLost(evt); call tfFocusLost(evt, tf2);

Answer (score 2):

Why not just creating your own class which extends `FocusAdapter` instead of creating an anonymous class for each of your `JTextField` :

```
public class MyFocusAdapter extends FocusAdapter {

    private final JTextField text;

    public MyFocusAdapter(JTextField text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this class :

```
tf1.addFocusListener(new MyFocusAdapter(tf1));
tf2.addFocusListener(new MyFocusAdapter(tf2));
```